# vue multiple prevent multiple clicks

Tags: vue.js

Im using a vuetify data table and have added a td element to download a pdf on a separate browser tab. `<td class="add-outline text-xs-left" style="cursor:pointer;" v-on:click.once.stop="openFile(props.item.pdfFile)" ><a target="_blank" :href="props.item.pdfFile"  style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">{{ props.item.reportDate }}</a></td>`

I have tried

```
v-on:click.once

v-on:click.stop
```

and

```
v-on:click.stop.once
```

my method only opens the new window

```
  openFile (url) {
      window.open(url)
    },
```

When i click it downloads the pdf twice. what is the best way to prevent this from happening?

this is what my click event looks like using vue dev tools
[image]

Comment: Can you use the browser dev tools to inspect that particular element and then on the elements tab (right sidebar) check the Event Listeners window, and see if there are any other event listeners attached to that element except for the one you add there. 
I just tried your case on a default vuetify datatable in this codepen, and I can't reproduce your issue. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGGNBb?editors=1011.

Comment: @8bit added an image of the click event on dev tools.

Comment: Seems fine. Can you check the this updated pen, the one before was missing the click event: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOOpXz?editors=1011
Is this similar to how you have it? Are you using the same default setup of the datatable or are you using one of the examples that has some added functionality e.g. row expansion?

Comment: Im not using any added functionality. It looks like this   <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="reports"
          v-model="selectedReports"
          :pagination.sync="pagination"
          :total-items="totalReports"
          :rows-per-page-items="pageItems"
          :loading="tableLoading"
          class="elevation-1 text-xs-center"
          item-key="key"
        >
          <v-progress-linear slot="progress" color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">

Comment: Can you make a codepen with the same code, check if it happens there too, if it does I can look and try to help.

Comment: I’ll work on a code pen from what I can tell my method is only called once. I can’t figure out why it would download twice